# Is it better to generate guid manually in my app or let sql server/azure sql generate it for me

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, azure-sql-database

How do I generate guid for my entities in my app that will be stored by entity framework to sql azure.

Right now I use `Id = Guid.NewGuid()`. Is this correct?

**EDIT**

To clarify why i'm asking this for, below is my explanations

My friend told me that sql server can generate guid with "NewID()". Right now i generate guid in my app using "Guid.NewGuid()". Which one should i use? For me, my current approach is more convenient because i get the guid value even before i save it to the database. What is the up/down side of each approach?

Comment: Your question could use some improvement. You will get a much better response if you read this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @matt Thanks for your inputs. I'll try to revised the question.

Comment: If you're using Guids as keys, take a look at this article on sqlskills.com: http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/kimberly/guids-as-primary-keys-andor-the-clustering-key/

Comment: For "normal" GUIDs it doesn't really matter. However, using [newsequentialid](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms189786.aspx) might lead to better paging/indexing on the sql server. Sadly this doesn't seem to be fully supported (yet?) resulting in "unknown default value/method" errors at design time (works at runtime, but is annoying). But as it also already have been pointed out, one makes ones life much easier, if one sees a (sql) database as "just another type of data storage" and doesn't rely too much on db-specific logic.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It really doesn't matter where you're generating the `Guid` because it is guaranteed to be unique in either case. But people coming from a `Domain Driven Design` background will suggest that generating it on the `C#` side is the correct approach as you can use it right away without having to query the database if the need arrives to update a different entity with that `Guid`.

Comment: Having the ID at your disposal right away is for me the reason why I generate the ID's in my code and not have the ID's generated by the server. This theoretically also makes it easier to switch to another database server.

Comment: I agree. As we move towards having the core business logic in `C#` and using the database as a datastore only, this has become an indispensable pattern.

Comment: But i read somewhere that guid generated by the database has better performance especially for clustering. Do you have any thought for that?

Comment: @Reynaldi - only when using [newsequentialid](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms189786.aspx). With the normal `newid()`, you get all the same problems.

Comment: @Reynaldi Yes with `NEWSEQUENTIALID()` you may have some performance benefits, otherwise for `NEWID()` is its all the same.